# Google Cloud VM memory is being used up 100%

Tags: boot, permissions, mount, disk-usage

I am not very good with ubuntu in general so forgive me if this question is a dumb one.

I recently started to use the Google Cloud service to mess around with some Machine Learning related things. I was busy pickling a database when I got [Errno 28] No Space Left on Device. I initially thought nothing of it and cleared a couple files and tried again, but I kept getting the error.

My instance is about 500 GB in size, but the files that I am currently playing around with take up less than 20 GBs of storage.

When I try `sudo du /home -sh /*` I get this:

```
476G   /home
14M /bin
46M /boot
0   /dev
7.3M    /etc
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
136M    /lib
3.9M    /lib32
4.0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
du: cannot access '/proc/5435/task/5435/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5435/task/5435/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5435/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5435/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
24K /root
8.6M    /run
13M /sbin
8.0K    /snap
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
24K /tmp
6.0G    /usr
2.9G    /var
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
```

And when I try using df to figure out hoe much memory I am using I get this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             24G     0   24G   0% /dev
tmpfs           4.8G  8.6M  4.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       485G  485G  427M 100% /
tmpfs            24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            24G     0   24G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/user/1001
```

Where is the 100% of memory usage coming from? I deleted a 39.9 GB sized dataset the other day, yet that only freed up a couple MBs of space.

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> 476G   /home
> ```

You rather clearly have 475GiB in a subdirectory of `/home/`

To get more information, free up some space (1-2GiB), run

```
sudo apt install ncdu
ncdu /home/
```

This will give you an interactive list of disk use.